# "Connecting...", "Connection failed. Activation of network connection failed" How to find out what does it mean exactly? (ping works)

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager, ipv6, ipv4

I've connected two PCs running Linux Mint 20.2 with `NetworkManager` with Ethernet cable. On enabling the interface PCs obtained ip6 addresses and I'm able to ping one from another. But I'm getting annoying GUI notification "activation of network connection failed" and status of wired connection in `NetworkManager` applet "Connecting...".

My initial guess was it is due to unable to obtain ip4 from DHCP, so I've disabled ip4 in GUI of `NetworkManager` for that wired connection. Still message remained the same. Then I've disabled `DNS` and `routes` again in GUI of `NetworkManager` for ip6 wired. Still message remained. Now however wired connection gets automatically disconnected completely per GUI of `NetworkManager` though leds on RJ45 remained lid/blinking with green/orange (after `sudo ifconfig eth down` leds turn off completely on PC where command is run). After some time connection via ip6 gets re-established for reasons yet unclear to me (`ping` again starts to gets replies).

What "Connecting...", "activation of network connection failed"  mean in the above situation?

I want a most simple scripted way to connect two PCs with Linux, preferably via ip6. As of now, as I see it, it works almost out-of-the-box, but those messages might interfere (and surely annoying and I've found not way to disable them in Cinnamon yet).

Added 1:

```
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8604] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <warn>  [1641876775.8655] device (enp0s25): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8660] device (enp0s25): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8836] dhcp4 (enp0s25): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8837] dhcp4 (enp0s25): state changed timeout -> done
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8879] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (*****)
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8900] device (enp0s25): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (*****)
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8938] device (enp0s25): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8944] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8947] device (enp0s25): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8956] device (enp0s25): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 04:52:55 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876775.8963] dhcp4 (enp0s25): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 11 04:53:40 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <warn>  [1641876820.8574] dhcp4 (enp0s25): request timed out
Jan 11 04:53:40 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876820.8575] dhcp4 (enp0s25): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jan 11 04:53:40 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876820.8577] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 04:53:40 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641876820.8600] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

Added 2:
Above added 1 was before ip4 was disabled, below when disabled there remained fewer lines (`dhcp4` gone):

```
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8456] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8478] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <warn>  [1641887353.8536] device (enp0s25): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8560] device (enp0s25): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8588] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (*****)
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8622] device (enp0s25): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (****)
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8627] device (enp0s25): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8639] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8647] device (enp0s25): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 07:49:13 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887353.8660] device (enp0s25): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 07:49:45 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887385.8471] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 11 07:49:45 mint NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1641887385.8497] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `NetworkManager`'s log messages. They should tell you in more detail what is happening and what is failing on your network connection.

On systems using `systemd-journald` as a primary log mechanism (such as modern Ubuntu/Mint), you'll need a command like this:

```
journalctl -x -b _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service
```

This will display all messages logged by NetworkManager since the latest system boot-up. The first line of output should be `-- Journal begins at <timestamp>, ends at <timestamp>. --` which tells you the time range of available journals (it is adjustable, but logs from before the beginning of the journal are already gone).

On systems with traditional `syslog` logging, you should usually look at logs stored in /var/log, e.g. `/var/log/daemon.log` (Debian/Ubuntu-based systems) or `/var/log/messages` (RedHat-style systems).

Your log indicates NetworkManager is still trying to get an IPv4 address by DHCP. It is using a connection definition named `Wired connection 1`:  you will be able to see how it is defined in detail if you type `nmcli connection show 'Wired connection 1'`. In particular, check:

```
nmcli connection show 'Wired connection 1' | grep method
```

The response should be about three lines, like this:

```
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv6.method:                            auto
proxy.method:                           none
```

For your use case, `ipv4.method` should be either `disabled` or `link-local`, and `ipv6.method` should probably be `link-local` too, to tell NetworkManager that a global internet connection is not expected with this connection definition.

See `man 5 nm-settings-nmcli` for details on each setting in the `nmcli connection show <connection name>` output. Note that they are organized hierarchically, so to find `ipv4.method` for example, you should first search for a section title `ipv4 setting` and then search for just `method` after that.

Comment: see Added 1. Many such sequences, last line same as first - start of next sequence.

Comment: added 2 for `ipv4` off

Comment: setting `link-local` for `ip6` (e.g. with `nmcli c m uuid ipv6.method link-local` - found on man page) resulted in `connection established`. I see now, PC tried to establish global connection? `reason 'ip-config-unavailable'`? But it got ip6 address, that got me confused.

Comment: Unlike with IPv4, an IPv6 global address does not *replace* a link-local address. Instead, an IPv6 network interface will always have one link-local IPv6 address (with a `fe80:` prefix) *and* zero or more globally routeable addresses. It seems NetworkManager needed an explicit information that only link-local connectivity is expected on this connection: without `ipv6.method link-local`, it was looking for something (anything!) more than that and unhappy about not finding anything.